# How to store data on the server permanently without the user having to register

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing an app with Flutter, which is similar in principle to the app "Celebrate". In this app I need to be able to store certain data on the server permanently without the user having to register. How can this be realised?

**Example:**

> 1. the user starts the app and creates an album
> 2. the user deletes the app
> 3. the user reinstalls the app
> 4. the previously created album is still there

I have thought about two possible variants. Which variant is the one I should prefer?

1. when the user starts the app, I store unique device information in the database on the server. So I always know to which device the corresponding data can be assigned. Does Apple even allow me to retrieve and store device information? Would this be a good solution?
2. I see that Firebase offers "Anonymous auth". Does that happen to do exactly what I need? In "Celebrate" it is so that even if you reinstall the app, the data will probably still be retrieved. So there is nothing stored locally. Could the developers of Celebrate use this or similar methods?

Thank you for a competent answer!

Comment: Speaking solely to (1), Apple (and other manufacturers, to an extent) generally prohibit this activity as it would enable extensive/invasive ad tracking, usually against a user's wishes. Unique identifiers allowed for use by apps in the App Store are generally reset when an app is re-installed (and last I checked, there was a mechanism to reset the identifier even without uninstalling).

Answer (score 1):

Getting a unique device ID seems more accurate solution for what you want. Firebase Anonymous Auth will not work if the user uninstall the app.

You could use [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) plugin developed by the Flutter team.

In your `pubspec.yaml` file add this:

```
dependencies:
  device_info: ^0.4.2+6 // or latest stable version when you see this
```

To get the data (and ID) of each platform:

```
// iOS
IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor; // unique ID on iOS
// Android
AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
androidDeviceInfo.androidId; // unique ID on Android
```

Since iOS vendor identifier can change on app reinstallation or other event, we need to keep it in the keychain with [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). You could simple check if the key exists or not. If it exists then it's a reinstallation, if doesn't, it's first time. And clearly, set the vendor id on first time.

Comment: Thank you :) What do you think about Apple and Android? Do both allow me to retrieve device information? Or do I rather expect a rejection of the app in the store?

Comment: I'm not sure. But since vendor identifier can change (see identifierForVendor docs), they are not that strict with it. I have seen other developers using this "trick" and they seem to have no problems with the review.

Answer (score 0):

> I see that Firebase offers "Anonymous auth". Does that happen to do exactly what I need?

While anonymous authentication would allow the user to get started without typing credentials, and you can still make them the "owner" of their own content, it *will* lose all knowledge of the user when you either sign them out or when they uninstall the app.

As @sqew commented, the scenario you describe is actually against Apple's guidelines, so even if it's technically possible it might not be the best choice.